# How does a .NET app redirect its own Standard Input stream?

Tags: c#, process, stream, ipc, stdin

I am attempting bidirectional communication (IPC) between 2 C# Apps using only Standard Input streams. The parent app launches the child app with a `Process`, where `RedirectStandardInput = true`. So the parent process is able to send commands to the child process using `childProc.StandardInput.WriteLine()`. I am capturing these messages asynchronously using `BeginRead()` and `EndRead()` of the stream acquired with `Console.OpenStandardInput()`. Parent to child communication is working great. I am able to send and receive messages asynchronously.

But when the child attempts to write to the parent, using the same code, .NET throws this error:

> StandardInput has not been redirected.

So, in simple terms, **how does a .NET app redirect its own standard input stream?** I will then redirect the standard input stream of my parent process, so the child can send messages to it.

My parent process is a WinForms C# App built with .NET 4.0 x86.

---

**Edit:** Here is the code of the IPC Server

```
internal class IPCServer {

    private Stream cmdStream;
    private byte[] cmdBuffer = new byte[4096];

    public IPCServer() {

        cmdStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(4096);

        GetNextCmd();
    }

    private void GetNextCmd() {

        // wait for next
        cmdStream.BeginRead(cmdBuffer, 0, cmdBuffer.Length, CmdRecived, null);
    }

    private void CmdRecived(IAsyncResult ar) {

        // input read asynchronously completed
        int bytesRead = 0;
        try {
            bytesRead = cmdStream.EndRead(ar);
        } catch (Exception) { }
        if (bytesRead > 0) {

            // accept cmd
            .........

            // wait for next
            GetNextCmd();
        }
    }


}
```

And here is the code of the IPC Client

```
internal class IPCClient {

    private Process appProc;

    public IPCClient(Process appProcess) {

        if (!appProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput) {
            //MessageBox.Show("IPCClient : StandardInput for process '" + appProcess.ProcessName + "' has not been 'redirected'!");
            return;
        }

        appProc = appProcess;

    }

    public void SendCmd(string cmd) {

        if (appProc != null) {
            appProc.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);
        }

    }

}
```

In the parent process:

```
// open child app
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(childProcPath, args);
info.WorkingDirectory = childProcDir;
info.LoadUserProfile = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;

childProc = Process.Start(info);

// connect to app for IPC
Client = new IPCClient();
Client.Init(childProc);

// recieve cmds from app
Server = new IPCServer();
Server.OnCmdRecieved = GotCmd;
Server.Init();
```

In the child process:

```
ownerProcess = ....

Server = new IPCServer();
Server.OnCmdRecieved = GotCmd;
Server.Init();

Client = new IPCClient();
Client.Init(ownerProcess);
```

Comment: Show some code instead of describing its principles in words.

Comment: Use shared memory if feasible

Comment: I/O redirection is a very ho-hum way to do IPC, having to use text and battling the encoding limitations and giving up on normal console usage is very little fun.  Use a named pipe instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the child process simply uses `BeginRead()` and `EndRead()` on the child process' StandardOutput stream. That should work!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a more convenient way. Just make your client application know nothing about input \ output redirection.
Server should bother about redirection.

I have implemented a simplest client-server application using your technique, which demonstrates how it should be used.

### Client

Client is a simplest application, which simply echoes the message back and closes when you enter `exit`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str;

    do
    {
        str = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Executed: " + str);
    } while (str != "exit");
}
```

The client knows nothing about redirection, it simply works like a console application and reads \ writes into a console.

### Server

Server runs client processes and reads \ writes in its streams.

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1.exe";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("a");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("b");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("c");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("d");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("f");

p.StandardInput.Close();

string res = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

After execution of this code, res contains the following text:

```
Executed: a
Executed: b
Executed: c
Executed: d
Executed: exit
```

Comment: Not possible this way, because the client app will be communicating asynchronously with the server. Its not a request/response system.